# Extract data from certain columns and only from rows with a certain value in one of the columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a workbook that has a worksheet with 14 columns of data (A - N). I want to extract some of this data and store it in another workbook.

I want to extract only columns A, B, F, H, I, K and L; and only from rows where column H contains **HCC**.

How can I do that?

Comment: google and learn how to use a pivot table, it will be a massive help in what you want to do

Comment: Thanks...that's what I'm seeing that others are recommending. Someone sent me something to work off of, but I need to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Learning about Pivot Tables is a great idea, but you can also do this with an array formula.

Put this formula in the first cell in column A of the second workbook where you want data to appear:

`=IFERROR(INDEX([Workbook1]Sheet1!A:A,SMALL(IF([Workbook1]Sheet1!$H:$H="HCC",ROW([Workbook1]Sheet1!$H:$H)),ROW())),"")`

Notes:

1. Replace "`[Workbook1]Sheet1!A:A`"` with the actual workbook and sheet names.  The easiest way to do this is, after you've entered the first part of the formula, navigate to the other workbook and click the "A" at the top of column A.
2. Ditto for both instances of "`[Workbook1]Sheet1!$H:$H`". You'll have to add the $'s.
3. Change the last "`ROW()`" to "`ROW() - n`", where n is 1 less than the row number you're putting the formula in.  If you're in row 1, you won't have to change it.
4. Finally, this is an array formula, so you need to enter it using <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just  <kbd>Enter</kbd> .  If entered correctly, the formula will be surrounded by curly braces {} in the formula bar.

Now, fill the formula down as far or farther that where you expect to have data in the future.  Last, copy that selected range and paste it into the first cell of all the other columns where you want to pull data from workbook 1. The formula will fill in blanks when it runs out of calculated values.

Next week, if you have more (or fewer) rows of data in the first workbook, the data will still be copied to the second workbook correctly.

**How it works:** The inner `IF()` checks where column H equals "HCC" and returns an array of the row numbers where that's True, and "`FALSE`" where it's not.  `SMALL()` takes that array and returns the numbers in order as the formula is filled down. `INDEX()` uses those numbers to return the corresponding values from column A. Finally the `IFERROR()` inserts blanks for errors generated where `INDEX()` runs out of row numbers as it's filled down.

I hope this helps, and good luck.